# CSS LESS color mixin not picking up new value

Tags: css, less

I have a navigation menu that pulls a unique color for each menu item. The LESS code is as follows:

```
@colors: #839B99, #D3B64F, #C84D26, #A787B0, #A8ACB1, #4F9E51;

.color-mix(@i) when (@i > 0) {
        .menu-item:nth-child(@{i}):hover {
            color: extract(@colors, @i - 1);
        }
    .color-mix(@i - 1);
}

.color-mix(6);
```

The change I made was adding a new item to the site's navigation menu, then adding `#A787B0` to the @colors array and bumping up .color-mix from `.color-mix(5)` to `.color-mix(6)`.

The problem I'm running into is that the menu nav on the site is not grabbing the new sequence/color. Instead, it's basically skipping over the new value:

- Menu item 1: #839B99
- Menu item 2: #D3B64F
- Menu item 3: #C84D26
- **Menu item 4: #A8ACB1** (this is the new menu item, and where the new array value (#A787B0) is being skipped
- Menu item 5: #4F9E51
- Menu item 6: black (default fallback color since no colors are left in the array)

Can anyone guide me on what I might be missing here?

Comment: can You try like that way "--color: #000;"